# Re-assigning String variables

Tags: java, string, input

When we work with multiple cases where in every time a new line of strings is to be accepted, what is the best way to store them?
(Something similar to what we get in programming contests)
For eg:
Say there are t cases that would be given as input by user. Then it is followed by t lines if input. So do we use arrays here? Or anything else?
If I use array as

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String input=sc.next();
```

this way wont be useful as input variable can be used only once, right?

Comment: The best option is to process the data as you get it. Many times when developers assume you need an array or list actually it is not needed.  If you do need to store the Strings, I suggest an ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use an ArrayList if you need to store the data. An [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is just like an array, except that it grows dynamically as you add elements to it.

Define it with:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then as the user enters something, write

```
myList.add(someStringVariable);
```

Comment: Do you need to place a pair of brackets after initialising your `ArrayList`? i.e. `new ArrayList<String>();`.

Comment: If you mean the < > brackets, then you don't strictly need them, but you should always use them. ArrayLists themselves are classes, but they are generics in that they can hold any object you want. Since you're holding Strings in this case, you should define it as above. If you wanted to hold some other object type, then you should define it as such. You can read a little about generics here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: And what if we have to use the split method of string to that input ? the split method returns an array of string. So how can we redeclare that array everytime with every test case?

Comment: You can easily convert from an array to an ArrayList. One way is with the Arrays.asList() method. If your array is called temp, you can write List<String> = Arrays.asList(temp);. I don't understand your last sentence re: redeclaring the array everytime with every test case.

Comment: I have 't' number of test cases from the user. With every t line of strings inserted I have to separated the line into its individual words which is done by the split function and then do the necessary operations. So with every new test case I have a new array of its words. So is there any way to re-initialize these arrays?

Comment: The split() function itself returns a new array that it creates which you can store in any variable. So you could easily declare a single array: String[] myArray; and everytime you read a new line, write myArray = t.split();, then do what you need to do with every word, then when you're done you just re-initialize it the same way.

Comment: So by the statement myArray=t.split() does the array size change everytime according to the no of words in the line??

Comment: Yes the size changes dynamically. Your reference variable, myArray, simply tells the compiler that this variable will point to some array later, of type String. When you call split(), it CREATES a NEW array, of some indeterminate size (it doesn't matter what size), then you set it up so that your reference variable is now connected to this returned array. Your reference variable can point to a million different arrays all of different sizes one by one, if you want.

Comment: And this same holds true for any String variable? for eg for myString=sc.nextLine() it will store the new line everytime or we need to nullify it first?

Comment: It holds true for any String variable that you call split() on. Split() is special in that it returns a NEW array.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a great help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Good luck with your project.